# C++ program output data to C#

Tags: c#, c++

Is there any simple way to get a few data variables from a C++ program into C#? Both programs would run on the same computer.

I need this to communicate the results of a C++ coded program (position: x,y (integer) and orientation (double)) to another device using C# coded sdk...

I am thinking along the lines of allocating a memory region then declaring it in a file, reading the file in C# to get the pointers and then working from there using a semaphore to control access.

Would this work? Any references on how to write something like that in both C# and C++?

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! The one example is shared memory: [Sharing variables between C# and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275264/sharing-variables-between-c-sharp-and-c) (that is what you mean with allocate memory and so on)

The second one is the "named pipes" method: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/420582/Inter-Process-Communication-between-Csharp-and-Cpl

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate between two separate processes in a lot of ways. I am pointing out a few of them -

- **Inter Process Communication** The first one I like is inter process communication, shortly known as **IPC**. There are a lot of articles on it. So I am not providing a code sample, you can get one from code project here -

[Inter-Process Communication between C# and C++ using named pipes](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/420582/Inter-Process-Communication-between-Csharp-and-Cpl)

- **Shared Memory** You can also use shared memory, I personally find it a little harmful, because it violates a rule to read and write in another programs memory. Here is an example -

[Sharing variables between C# and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275264/sharing-variables-between-c-sharp-and-c)

- **Database** Its only possible if both of your programs use same database. Very easy, you already know it. But only works in limited cases.
- **Your own Custom Implementation** Example would be writing in a file in a location and then making that file accessible to both the programs.

Pick your choice !!!... Personally I would go for IPC for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that both programs are running on the same system, a simple solution would be to write the output of your C++ program to a file and use this file as input for a C# program. Maybe you can use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) on the C# side to monitor that file for changes.

Some more links:

[How to write to a file in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4442/)

[How to read a file in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx)