# C++ Specify Actual Size of Struct

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, memory-alignment, packing

I've come across a problem with interop between C# and C++ where I'm sharing memory between the two 'sides' of my application via a struct defined in both native and managed code. The struct on the native side is defined as such:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
        struct RayTestCollisionDesc {
                btVector3 hitPosition;
                btRigidBody* hitBody;

                RayTestCollisionDesc(btRigidBody* body, btVector3& position)
                        : hitBody(body), hitPosition(position) { }
        };
#pragma pack(pop)
```

And a similar struct is defined on the managed (C#) side. On C# the struct size is 20 bytes (as I would expect on a 32-bit system). However, despite the `pragma pack` directive, the struct size on the C++ size is still 32. For clarity here's the `sizeof()` from C++ of each of those types:

```
sizeof(btVector3) : 16 
sizeof(btRigidBody*) : 4
sizeof(RayTestCollisionDesc) : 32
```

Clearly `pragma pack` is only referring to packing between members of the struct, and not padding at the end of the struct (i.e. alignment). I also tried adding `__declspec(align(1))` but that had no effect, and MSDN itself does say *"__declspec(align(#)) can only increase alignment restrictions."*

And FWIW I'm using the VS2013 compiler (Platform Toolset v120).

Is there a way to 'force' the struct size to 20 bytes?

Comment: `btVector3` is likely aligned at a 16 byte boundary to enable SSE intrinsics. How about adding explicit padding so that the struct always *is* 32 bytes?

Comment: Maybe the problem is on the C# side? I don't know anything about this, but judging from the number of questions on SO, it seems easy to get it wrong. This one looks like a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275264/sharing-variables-between-c-sharp-and-c

Comment: @Jens The answer in that question is pretty much what I've implemented (packing set to 1 on both sides). In terms of what I'd expect, the C# side is 'correct' (i.e. 20 bytes, no overhead). However I think Bo Persson above probably has figured out why the compiler refuses not to align the struct; because btVector3 is indeed SSE-enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are transferring data between two different compilers. In general, it is impossible to make this match. Especially if you transfer data from one computer to another.

First write a spec for the data that you are transferring. The spec CANNOT be a C++ or C# struct. The spec must be something like "four bytes this, four bytes that, two bytes a third thing..." and so on "with a total of 20 bytes", for example.

Then whether you use C++ or C#, or whether a totally different developer uses Objective-C code to read the data, you read an array of 20 bytes, take the 20 bytes, look at them, and fill whatever struct you want with these 20 bytes. And for writing, you do the opposite. Now it does not matter what C++ compiler you use, what weird pragmas you are using, it just works.

Or use something portable like JSON.

Comment: or, in short, implement serialisation

Comment: I disagree; PInvoke and the attributes it provides are meant exactly to support this kind of scenario, and Win32 C++ compilers do have additional guarantees besides what is required by the standard exactly to allow interoperability with the system APIs and the COM ABI; most of the Win32 <=> .NET plumbing is done exactly through PInvoke, and non-trivial `struct` are routinely marshaled transparently by using the appropriate PInvoke declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do interop this way. A C# object and a C++ struct are different. I suggest you tu use a serialization library like Capt'n Proto or Protobuf

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I don't think this is a viable solution in this case - the reason I'm sharing memory in this way in the first place is for performance reasons. If I was comfortable serializing the data I'd just go through P/Invoke, anyway. I understand that Protobuf and Capt'n Proto are very fast- but ultimately they'd be an unnecessary overhead- I think gnasher's answer is more suitable.