# how to use Protocol Buffers for data transfer from c++ to c#

Tags: c++, .net, protocols, protocol-buffers

I want to serialize an object in C++, send it to c# and deserialize it there. What is the fastest way to do this for a simple class such as:

```
class Person
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

Comment: try this might it will help on your question [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275264/sharing-variables-between-c-sharp-and-c)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ protogen tools really want you to use a .proto schema, so: you need to describe your intent in .proto; fortunately, that's simple:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message Person {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Then, at least for the C++ part, you need to run that through google's `protoc` tooling to output the C++ stubs, and work with that. For the C# part, you have (at least) 2 choices: you can do the same thing with `protoc` to generate C#, or you can use protobuf-net which is happy to work *either* with types generated from .proto (via `protogen` - protobuf-net's equivalent of `protoc`), *or* from simple annotated types. For example, in C# with protobuf-net your above type will work with simply:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    int id;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    string name;
}
```

In either case (protoc or protogen), you might find [this online tool useful](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/#g27da42b74f54657dbf7e9c48be22c34d) in terms of playing with the code-gen step.

That done: use the library-specific serialize mechanism, and you should be fine.